# ¿Se puede indicar a Git que no guarde un commit determinado?

Tags: git

Tengo un *commit en la rama master*, con unos cambios necesarios para que un proyecto web funcione en producción, esos mismos cambios impiden que el mismo proyecto funcione en local. Hay una forma de indicarle a Git (en local) que se traiga la rama remota ignorando ese *commit* concreto?
Es decir, tener un histórico en remoto como:

```
otro commit
cambios para remoto
un commit
```

y en local:

```
otro commit
un commit
```

para la misma rama.

Comment: No sé con qué lenguaje trabajas pero me parece una mala idea. ¿Por qué no crear *perfiles* o *contextos de entorno* que modifiquen el comportamiento de tu aplicación dependiendo de si estás en producción o desarrollo?

Comment: @PabloLozano es un buen punto. En realidad es una versión para producción de una aplicación *React*, un problema con las importaciones de `@fontface` desde el CSS de una librería de terceros. Funcionan en el servidor de producción si empiezan las URIs por / y en local por ./ De ahí que se me ocurriera la cuestión.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

No es posible

---

Ya que un repositorio git guarda toda la historia del repositorio como una secuencia de commits, no es posible que quieras usar la **misma** rama pero que tenga **2 históricos** diferentes, porque al final tu rama local va a ser un reflejo del remoto.

Cómo te recomienda @pablo-lozano, lo ideal es tener algún archivo de configuracion o variables de contexto (no incluidas en el repositorio) que te permitan modificar la ejecución de tu aplicación dependiendo de factores externos al repo (como tu entorno: desarrollo, producción, pruebas, etc)